# Chosen plaintext attack on Blum–Goldwasser cryptosystem

Tags: chosen-ciphertext-attack, blum-blum-shub

As I was reading on some encryption schemes the other day, I stumbled upon the Blum–Goldwasser cryptosystem and read that it is vulnerable to adaptive chosen ciphertext attack.
I searched for some actual example but could not find any, so I thought asking here for anyone willing to provide a simple proof of concept chosen ciphertext attack on the Blum–Goldwasser cryptosystem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The cryptosystems ultimately in a stream cipher like fashion, have a look at the security of similar schemes and see if you can adapt those? For example, the CTR mode for blockciphers. And if you are lucky, you may even find the answer on this server!